# Multiple intersections problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, intersections

Imagine you draw two lines like:

[image]

Now imagine you want to draw crossing jumps for the blue line over the red line. You may write the same code as me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{circuitikzgit}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newlength{\crossing}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\crossing}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/crossing/size}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw [name path = one, color=red] (0,-1) |- (0.5,0.5) |- (1,-1);
\draw [name path = two, color=blue] (-0.5,0) --  (1.5,0);

\path[name intersections={of=one and two,by=i}];
\fill[color=white] (i) circle[radius=0.5\crossing];
\draw (i) node[jump crossing]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

But after you compile this you will find that only the first intersection is jumped, the other one is not:
[image]

**Forget about the blue and red colors** I only draw the lines like that to show you how the lines were laid down.

How do I make the blue line to jump at **every** intersection with the red line or other lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `intersections` library allows you to find out how many intersections there are and you can loop over them, see p. 145 of pgfmanual v3.1.5:

[image]

All I am doing here is to apply this to your example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{circuitikzgit}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newlength{\crossing}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\crossing}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/crossing/size}\pgf@circ@Rlen}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw [name path = one, color=red] (0,-1) |- (0.5,0.5) |- (1,-1);
  \draw [name path = two, color=blue] (-0.5,0) --  (1.5,0);

  \path[name intersections={of=one and two,name=i,total=\t},fill=white]
  foreach \X in {1,...,\t} {(i-\X) circle[radius=0.5\crossing]
  (i-\X) node[jump crossing]{}};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, have a nice day wherever you are, I could not come to terms with that loop. Thank you again and happy new year.

Comment: @ElSabio You're welcome and Happy New Year!